# Cygwin libzint(zint) goes into infinite loop

Tags: c++, cygwin

Cygwin Zint(libzint) stucks on `ZBarcode_Create()` function call with basic example code which perfectly works on Linux system:

```
#include <zint.h>
int main()
{
    struct zint_symbol *my_symbol;my_symbol = ZBarcode_Create();
    if(my_symbol != NULL)
    {
        printf("Symbol successfully created!\n");
    }
    ZBarcode_Delete(my_symbol);
    return 0;
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Downloaded and installed Cygwin, zlib, libpng and libzint(zint) packages
- In Visual Studio created a new project, added Include Path, added libzint.a library name, added library path in Linker options
- Added Cygwin path to PATH variable
- Tried to build libzint by myself result is the same

Can someone help me to find out is it common behavior for libs that were created with Cygwin or is it only Zint(libzint)?

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine. After installing the needed libraries with cygwin setup and
checking their presence

```
$ cygcheck -cd |grep zint
libzint-devel                           2.4.3-3
libzint2.4                              2.4.3-3
zint                                    2.4.3-3
```

the compilation is without any problem and the testing also

```
$ gcc -o prova prova.c -Wall -lzint
$ ./prova.exe
Symbol successfully created!
```